# Proving triangle inequality geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

If $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are vectors, how can you prove geometrically that
$$
\|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\|\leq\|\mathbf{u}\|+\|\mathbf{v}\|
$$

I am aware of the proof that uses dot product but I do not know how to prove it geometrically. This is exercise 12 of section 3.2 of Anton Elementary linear algebra (application version), 9th edition.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a picture. The three vectors $u$, $v$, and $u+v$ are edges of a triangle which we use to visualize addition of vectors (see [the Wikipedia article on this topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_addition#Addition_and_subtraction)). The result then follows from the fact that the sum of the lengths of two sides of a triangle cannot be less than the length of the third side.